# More up votes then down votes and still unable to ask new questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, moderator, up-votes

I understand that down votes equal privilege being suspended. I have a positive on the total up votes and refined questions but still cannot ask new questions. Is there a minimum up vote count per question I must keep in order to keep asking questions?

Comment: delete the questions you have asked...hope it may work

Comment: @goodyzain Please see the post I linked below. That will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muze, actually, the reason you can't ask questions is not because you lack the privilege, but because you have been automatically blocked by the system for asking too many low quality questions.

Please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) for more information and how to possibly lift the auto ban.

Comment: Can it be undone?

Comment: @Muze No, not by moderators. The post I linked has details about how you can try to reverse it.